# Application to browse time stamped data of different type

Tags: data-visualization, data-analysis

Application to browse time stamped data of different types (email, phone call, sms, photo, document, web browser history, ...) as one timeline to scroll through.

**Requirements**

- OS: Linux, preferably Ubuntu
- Platform: x86

**Manual workaround** (inconvenient)

1. save each email, phone call, sms, ... as *one separate file* (setting the time stamp of the file according to the time stamp of the data element)
2. copy all files in one folder
3. then browse the folder with a file manager, sorting by date

**What the application should do**

1. scan a given directory tree and/or mobile device or other data source (network)
2. combine all scanned data in one visual timeline to scroll through continuously
3. display some thumbnail/excerpt for each item
4. display relevant meta data such as time stamp, sender, recipient, ... for each item
5. allow clicking on the item to open it (with the preferred application for the respective data type)

I guess intelligence agencies already use such software, but I haven't yet found anything on the net.

Comment: Might be useful to add what OS you want that for.

Comment: This is a very interesting question - just specify what OS / platform it needs to run on and it'll be perfect.

Comment: Fixed? Still need to be on hold?

Comment: I think the current title doesn't really express well what is meant ... I'd rather give the following title: **Application to browse diverse time stamped data (email, sms, photo, web browser history, ...) merged in a timeline**

Answer (score 1):

List of projects related to the question, source: https://karl-voit.at/tagstore/downloads/Voit2012b.pdf

- Lifestreams: Organizing your Electronic Life (1995) http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.48.6769&rank=4
- TimeScape / Time-Machine Computing: A Time-centric Approach for the Information Environment https://www2.sonycsl.co.jp/person/rekimoto/papers/uist99.pdf
- MyLifeBits: a personal database for everything: *"... interface was the MyLifeBits shell, which visualized queries as a list containing thumbnails of images and a **timeline view** ..."* https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/mylifebits-a-personal-database-for-everything/?from=http%3A%2F%2Fresearch.microsoft.com%2Fpubs%2F64157%2Ftr-2006-23.pdf

Available software:

- "What did I do on February 14th 2007? Visualize your (digital) life in Org-mode" https://github.com/novoid/Memacs
- Timerliner - All your digital life on a single timeline, stored locally https://github.com/mholt/timeliner (added 2022-03-02)